# ant design tooltip shows scroll bar

Tags: reactjs

I am using ant design with react for my project
when I am using the tooltip component, and I hover over the element, the tooltip appears and the scroll bar for a half-second and then disappears.
as you can see in this video https://youtu.be/Tyg61JVDgRc

anybody knows why?

Comment: when you hover it its look like it add overflow scroll in CSS can you check it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

at the moment the problem is only with ant design tooltip component, and is bugging and not following the position : 'fixed' so handing it to overlayStyle prop manually will fix the problem like `<Tooltip overlayStyle={{position:'fixed'}}/>`, I hope this helps. if youre still in trouble pass destroyTooltipOnHide propery